# How to add custom Woocommerce data on Wootheme's Certificate?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woothemes

I have added custom fields to Woocommerce's checkout page.

I'm looking to take data from the custom field and place it on Wootheme's certificate plugin.

Here is an existing segment of code for woo theme's Certificate plugin. I know the answer lay in replacing the value of `$certificate_heading` to change what data it is drawing.

```
$certificate_heading = __( 'Certificate of Completion', 'sensei-certificates' ); // Certificate of Completion
    if ( isset( $this->certificate_template_fields['certificate_heading']['text'] ) && '' != $this->certificate_template_fields['certificate_heading']['text'] ) {

        $certificate_heading = $this->certificate_template_fields['certificate_heading']['text'];
        $certificate_heading = str_replace( array( '{{learner}}', '{{course_title}}', '{{completion_date}}', '{{course_place}}'  ), array( $student_name, $course->post_title, date( 'jS F Y', strtotime( $course_end_date ) ), get_bloginfo( 'name' ) ) , $certificate_heading );
    } // End If Statement
```

Here is a line of code that shows how the admin panel of Woocommerce pulls and displays one of the custom fields that I created on the checkout page:

```
echo '<p><strong>'.__('Student Drivers License').':</strong> ' . get_post_meta( $order->id, 'Student Drivers License', true ) . '</p>';
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get data from a custom field with

```
<?php
 get_post_meta($wpo_wcpdf->export->order->id,'Your field name',true);
?>
```

In the same file as you found `$certificate_heading`, find the `$student_name` variable and change it to be the value of the field name you are looking for.